# Connecting nodemcu through internet

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, networking, website

I have a NodeMCU and a website (free website domain provided by hpage.com) and I have to send and receive some data (suppose a 8-bit number) from the website to the NodeMCU via internet.

The NodeMCU is connected to internet through WiFi hotspot of an Android phone.

Can anyone provide an example code?

I have seen the system working on WiFi LAN, and I don't want to limit it to local network.

- How can I address the NodeMCU from the website?
- Does the NodeMCU need to be a server or just a client?

Thanks in advance for kind help. I can't use a WiFi router, I have to use a android phone hotspot in this case.

Comment: pushing _to_ the site isn't a problem. Pushing _from_ the site require poking through the firewall, but you shouldn't need to do that anyway,

Comment: Yes, that's where the real problem arise. But, when I request anything to the webserver, can't the server send some data by then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit difficult to address local device from the internet due to the protection provided by the firewall.

There are may ways to solve this problem (i.e. opening a port on the router, creating a server to address queries coming from the internet etc.).

I use Firebase as an external database and make my NodeMCU such that it listens to changes on the Firebase real time database.

- You can integrate firebase with your website and using the website you can update database values.
- Whenever a value is changed the NodeMCU will respond to it.
- Example code for the same can be obtained from the internet. There are many tutorials, videos on this topic which you can go through.

Comment: That's a good idea to use firebase for database. Is there any way to directly communicate with the nodemcu from the website? If I can send and receive an 8 bit data after a few milliseconds delay, that would be enough for me. I can't open a port of router as I am using an Android phone as wifi router, is there any way to do that?

Comment: If I create a server in nodemcu to address queries from internet as you said will it affect the working of nodemcu as a client to the web server? Can I use php to connect the nodemcu server from website when I have one?